# CUPS The address wasn't understood on Firefox and External Protocol Request on Chromium

Tags: printing

When Im going to manage the printer on CUPS, this error shows on **Firefox**:

The address wasn't understood

Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because one of the following protocols (ipps) isn't associated with any program or is not allowed in this context.

You might need to install other software to open this address.

And when Im going to do that thing on **Chromium** this what shows:

Chromium need to launch application to handle ipps:links. The link requested is ipps://is ipps://er.local.631/printers/EPSON-L110-Series.

The following application will be launched if you accept this request:

xdg-open

If you did not initiate this request, it may represent an attempted attack on your system. Unless you took an explicit action to initiate this request, you should press Do Nothing.

--I click Launch Application but nothing happened.

This problem happened only today, but before this CUPS works correctly.

Sorry im a newbie on ubuntu, nothing shows on the internet how to solve it